# Python 2.7 - Can't get full list/array from my for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, output, nested-loops

I am working on a program that can convolve two lists and I need to do it from scratch. I have the correct output from my for loop, however I can't return it because the appended output will only save the last iteration of the for loop. I've tried enumerate, append, extend, and several others, I just don't know python enough to get a list or ideally an array of ints from my for loop. 
    import numpy as np

```
#def conv395(x,h):
    #Function to convolve x input signal and h impulse response

h = [1,2,-1,1]
x = [1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1]    
M = len(h)-1
L = len(x)
Ly = M+L


def ConV(x,h,n):
    y = (h[m]*x[(n-1)-m])
    return (y)

for n in range(0,Ly+1):

    mx = n-L+1

    if mx < 1:
        n = n+1
        #print("SPACE")
        Y1 = 0

        if n <= M+1:

            Y = []
            for m in range(n):
                #print(n) 

                y = ConV(x,h,n)
                Y1 = y + Y1

            Y.append(Y1)
            print Y,
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1] [3] [3] [5]
```

*HOWEVER*

```
Y type=list size=1 Value=[5]
```

I need the Value to match the output in a list or array.
Any help would be greatly appreciated,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```
h = [1,2,-1,1]
x = [1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1]    
M = len(h)-1
L = len(x)
Ly = M+L
LOL = []

def ConV(x,h,n):
    y = (h[m]*x[(n-1)-m])
    return (y)

for n in range(0,Ly+1):

    mx = n-L+1

    if mx < 1:
        n = n+1
        #print("SPACE")
        Y1 = 0

        if n <= M+1:

            Y = []
            for m in range(n):
                #print(n) 

                y = ConV(x,h,n)
                Y1 = y + Y1

            Y.append(Y1)
            LOL.append(Y)
            print Y, 

print LOL
```

Comment: #facepalm --- yep, this worked...smh*** Thank you so much, I tried pretty much every variation I could to get this output lol! It's the little things!